# Can I number assumptions to coincide with subsequent theorems?

Tags: amsmath, theorems, counters

I have TeX which defines `theorem` and `assumption` environments with `\newtheorem`, and it correctly resets the assumption counter after each theorem.

[image: counters off by one]

The numbering *currently* means:

- Assumptions 0.1 and 0.2 are relevant to theorem 1
- Assumptions 1.1 and 1.2 are relevant to theorem 2

But that's awkward.  It would be *better* if the numbering were such that:

- Assumptions 1.1 and 1.2 were related to theorem 1
- Assumptions 2.1 and 2.2 were related to theorem 2

Is there a reasonable way to achieve this?

TeX:

```latex
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}[theorem]

\begin{document}


\begin{assumption} \label{a}
    Object $\mathcal{A}$ is great.
\end{assumption}

\begin{assumption} \label{b}
    Object $\mathcal{B}$ is truly wonderful.
\end{assumption}

\begin{theorem}
    Subject to Assumptions \ref{a} and \ref{b}, $\mathcal{A} \bigoplus \mathcal{B} = \mathcal{B}$.
\end{theorem}


\begin{assumption} \label{aa}
    Object $\mathfrak{A}$ is awful.
\end{assumption}

\begin{assumption} \label{bb}
    Object $\mathfrak{B}$ is truly terrible.
\end{assumption}

\begin{theorem}
    Subject to Assumptions \ref{aa} and \ref{bb}, $\mathfrak{A} \bigotimes \mathfrak{B} = \mathfrak{B}$.
\end{theorem}


\end{document}
```

If I use `\setcounter` on the `assumption` counter at the beginning, it changes the N in 0.N.  And if I use `\setcounter{theorem}{1}` at the beggining, then the problem persists, just offset by 1.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Will assumptions ever be "out of order" with respect to theorems, as in, might assumptions relevant to theorem 4 ever appear earlier, e.g., before theorem 3?  Or might assumptions for different theorems ever be interleaved?  If the order is consistently as you describe it, one additional counter would probably work.  (Not coded or tested.)

Comment: Yes I think there will exist assumptions like that.  I suppose those should be an entirely separate counter?  Or perhaps you have something else in mind.

Comment: Ah, just noticed your edit.  Assumptions relevant to theorem N might appear before theorem N-1, yes.  But I will place those on a separate, global counter, so that they are numbered as Assumptions 1, 2, ... rather than *.1, *.2, etc.  So I'm only asking about the assumptions which precede each theorem and are relevant to that theorem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DIY `\theassumption`, and force it to add 1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}[theorem]


%%%% THE KEY LINE BELOW
\renewcommand\theassumption{\the\numexpr\thetheorem + 1\relax.\arabic{assumption}}
%%%%

\begin{document}


\begin{assumption} \label{a}
    Object $\mathcal{A}$ is great.
\end{assumption}

\begin{assumption} \label{b}
    Object $\mathcal{B}$ is truly wonderful.
\end{assumption}

\begin{theorem}
    Subject to Assumptions \ref{a} and \ref{b}, $\mathcal{A} \bigoplus \mathcal{B} = \mathcal{B}$.
\end{theorem}


\begin{assumption} \label{aa}
    Object $\mathfrak{A}$ is awful.
\end{assumption}

\begin{assumption} \label{bb}
    Object $\mathfrak{B}$ is truly terrible.
\end{assumption}

\begin{theorem}
    Subject to Assumptions \ref{aa} and \ref{bb}, $\mathfrak{A} \bigotimes \mathfrak{B} = \mathfrak{B}$.
\end{theorem}


\end{document}
```

(Note that this assumes you want to print theorem numbers always as arabic numerals.)

Answer (score 3):

You can define an `assumption` environment that takes as argument the label given for the theorem it refers to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{refcount}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newtheorem{assumptioninner}{Assumption}
\newcounter{assumption}
\newenvironment{assumption}[1]
 {% #1 is the label of the corresponding theorem
  \ifcsname assumption@#1\endcsname
    % not the first assumption, advance
    \expandafter\xdef\csname assumption@#1\endcsname{%
      \the\numexpr\csname assumption@#1\endcsname+1\relax
    }%
  \else
    \expandafter\xdef\csname assumption@#1\endcsname{1}%
  \fi
  \renewcommand{\theassumptioninner}{\getrefnumber{#1}.\csname assumption@#1\endcsname}%
  \assumptioninner
 }
 {\endassumptioninner}

\begin{document}

\begin{assumption}{first}\label{a}
    Object $\mathcal{A}$ is great.
\end{assumption}

\begin{assumption}{first}\label{b}
    Object $\mathcal{B}$ is truly wonderful.
\end{assumption}

\begin{assumption}{second}\label{aa}
    Object $\mathfrak{A}$ is awful.
\end{assumption}

\begin{theorem}\label{first}
    Subject to Assumptions \ref{a} and \ref{b},
    $\mathcal{A} \bigoplus \mathcal{B} = \mathcal{B}$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{assumption}{second}\label{bb}
    Object $\mathfrak{B}$ is truly terrible.
\end{assumption}

\begin{theorem}\label{second}
    Subject to Assumptions \ref{aa} and \ref{bb},
    $\mathfrak{A} \bigotimes \mathfrak{B} = \mathfrak{B}$.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

I believe there might be a way to automatically number assumptions based on the following theorem. Not if assumptions are not required to only precede the theorem they refer to.

[image]

The code has been tested with and without `hyperref`.